# AceFEM GlobalTask

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I wonder whether there is any way to add data directly to the linear equation system in AceFEM.
I´m having external data that I want to superimpose to the linear system before solving it. The targeted systems are quite huge, which stresses the need for a performant solution.

My current plan is to use an AceFEM GlobalTask to read the data file directly and then access the memory for the tangent and right-hand side vector.

My question is how to access these fields from the GlobalTask.

Of course, I'm interested in any different solution to the problem. Currently, I'm using a global element that has the data loaded into its ElementData and is connected to all DOFS to export an element tangent that is of system size.

Thanks in advance for ur help!

Comment: Hi,

Tangent matrix memory cannot be directly accessed. In FEM tangent matrix is sparse and stored in compressed format.

From your description, one can conclude that your tangent matrix is full. Right?

Comment: Hi, yes it's pretty dense.

Comment: That is bad. Can you show the result of SMTSimulationReport[].

Answer (score 0):

@JozeK This is the corresponding SMTSimulationReport[] output.

[image]

Comment: Obviously, what you did is probably already optimal. 88% of the time is spent by Intel MKL linear solver. Large dense matrices are extremely costly to triangulate (time is proportional to n^3).  A bit mysterious is only that you have Number of threads is 0?